# How can I identify the arguments that will be passed to a particular IL method call in Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, .net, il, mono.cecil

I am using Mono.Cecil to do some analysis and rewriting on an assembly. In some cases this is pretty easy: you can just look right before the call to see where the arguments are loaded:

```
// Math.Pow(2, 4)
IL_0001:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 
IL_000A:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 10 40 
IL_0013:  call        System.Math.Pow
```

However, this gets more complicated when the arguments to the function are themselves complex expressions:

```
// Math.Pow(2, Math.Abs(Math.Max(17, "123".GetHashCode())));
IL_0001:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 
IL_000A:  ldc.i4.s    11 
IL_000C:  ldstr       "123"
IL_0011:  callvirt    System.Object.GetHashCode
IL_0016:  call        System.Math.Max
IL_001B:  call        System.Math.Abs
IL_0020:  conv.r8     
IL_0021:  call        System.Math.Pow
```

In this case, a bunch of stuff happens between when the first argument is loaded  and when the second argument is loaded. I'm wondering: does Mono.Cecil expose any tools for finding the IL instructions responsible for pushing each argument?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? The question is a little underdefined because there is not necessarily one instruction per argument (as you have recognized).

Comment: @usr given an instruction which calls a function (e. g. call, newobj), I want to identify the instructions reponsible for pushing each final argument value. In the example above, I want the initial ldc.r8 and the conv.r8.

Answer (score 2):

ILSpy is an open source IL to C# decompiler based on Cecil and it can be also used as [a library called ICSharpCode.Decompiler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ICSharpCode.Decompiler/). It can transform IL to "IL AST", which I think is exactly what you're asking for.

If you use it like this:

```
var decompiled = new ILAstBuilder().Build(method, true, new DecompilerContext(module));
var block = new ILBlock(decompiled);
new ILInlining(block).InlineAllVariables();
```

Then for the following method (compiled in Release mode):

```
static double F()
{
    return Math.Pow(2, Math.Abs(Math.Max(17, "123".GetHashCode())));
}
```

The variable `block` will contain:

```
ret(call(Math::Pow, ldc.r8(2), conv.r8(call(Math::Abs, call(Math::Max, ldc.i4(17), callvirt(object::GetHashCode, ldstr("123")))))));
```

Note that I have no experience using ICSharpCode.Decompiler, so there might be a better way to do this.